# Is having many build-once factories a sign of bad dependency injection design?

Tags: c#, object-oriented-design, dependency-injection, factory, onion-architecture

I have a form. It contains things like grids. Users do things with these grids and what they do with them is sent to a SQL server. Clearly, the server is a volatile dependency and should be dependency injected.

Of course, it would be silly to have the form know about my business logic, so all of the business logic to do with the grids is in individual classes. Let's call where these classes live my "business logic layer" and where my form the lives the "UI layer". Since my classes in the business logic layer need to know about the server and the server is a volatile dependency, those classes should take the relevant details about the server in their constructor. For example, the class holding the business logic for `FooCells` in the grid (let's call it `FooCellsHandler`) should take an `IFooSqlRepository` in its constructor and that `IFooSqlRepository` parameter should be passed a `FooSqlRepository`.

So far, our composition root looks something like this:

```csharp
private static RootType CompRoot(string SqlConnString)
{
    return
        new Form1(
            new FooCellsHandler(
                new FooSqlRepository(
                    new SqlContext(SqlConnString)
                )
            )
        )
    ;
}
```

And although the indentation is ugly, it's all fine... As long as the only argument that `FooCellHandler` needs is the `IFooSqlRepository`. If it needs extra arguments at runtime, let's say `CellHeader` and `CellValue`, then we can't have those in our composition root. We therefore need to make a factory. Our composition root will still be the same, but with `FooCellsHandler` replaced with `FooCellsHandlerFactory`. This factory object will only constructed once in the entire application. Here is one such possible `FooCellsHandler` and its factory.

```csharp
public class TimeCellHandler
{
  private readonly int _value;
  private readonly string _header;
  private readonly ITimeCellSqlRepository _repo;
  
  public TimeCellHandler(int CellValue, string CellHeader, ITimeCellSqlRepository Repo)
  {
      _value = CellValue;
      _header = CellHeader;
      _repo = Repo;
  }

  private void FormatForServer()
  {
    // Helper method used by others.
  }
  
  public void DeleteFromServer()
  {
     // Deletes values corresponding to this time cell from the server.
  }

  public void InsertToServer()
  {
     // Inserts values corresponding to this time cell to the server.
  }
}

public class TimeCellHandlerFactory
{
    private readonly ITimeCellSqlRepository _repo;
    public TimeCellHandlerFactory(ITimeCellSqlRepository Repo)
    {
        _repo = Repo;
    }

    public TimeCellHandler MakeHandler(int CellValue, string CellHeader)
    {
        return TimeCellHandler(CellValue, CellHeader, _repo);
    }
}
```

**Is having many build-once factories a sign of bad dependency injection design?** I see many reasons to be suspicious of it. Because my form handles many different things, I can imagine that my composition root will contain many such factories and begin to look something like the below. This seem ugly, repeats my SQL information a great many times, and puts many layers of indirection between what my form is supposed to do and how it is being done.

```csharp
private static RootType CompRoot2(string SqlConnString)
{
    return
        new Form1(
            new FooCellsHandlerFactory(
                new FooSqlRepository(
                    new SqlContext(SqlConnString)
                )
            ),
            new BarCellsHandlerFactory(
                new BarSqlRepository(
                    new SqlContext(SqlConnString)
                )
            ),
            new OtherCellsHandlerFactory(
                new OtherSqlRepository(
                    new SqlContext(SqlConnString)
                )
            ),
            new MyColumnHandlerFactory(
                new MyColumnSqlRepository(
                    new SqlContext(SqlConnString)
                )
            ),
            new EdgeCaseHandlerFactory(
                new EdgeCaseSqlRepository(
                    new SqlContext(SqlConnString)
                )
            ),
        )
    ;
}
```

Comment: A popular IoC container/framework for .NET can clean this up by hiding away the composition root and allow lambdas as factories instead (which is ideal for this use case).  Consider using `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection).    Also, if you're using EF Core, then there's a further useful extension method to clean it up a little more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/   (Works well with Configuration from appSettings.json too)

Comment: @BenCottrell That's great, but my question is only if what I've described is a bad sign. How to fix it, if it is a problem, is a different question.

Comment: Usually, factories are single instances but It's not a must.  While new instances can be legit, it has a computational cost. If this cost is backed by good reasons, then fine, if not, it's probably code smell. Or,.maybe the name is not the best one. The thing is, are factories stateful? If yes? Does the state changes after initialization? If not, seems reasonable to have single instances

Comment: .. can we talk about spacing?

Comment: @Ewan better now?

Comment: I think I need to know more about these "build once factories" you are making. I think that maybe _they_ are the bad design not the DI requiremetns

Comment: on a spacing related note a college recently introduced me to C#'s "work out the type for you" feature means you can do : `new Form1(new(new(new(SqlConnectionString),new(new(new(SqlConnectionString),new(new(new(SqlConnectionString),new(new(new(SqlConnectionString),new(new(new(SqlConnectionString))`

Comment: @Ewan I think I've said all that can be said about them. Because the `Handler` class' constructor requires both the fixed argument of the SQL connection and the runtime arguments that I've called `CellHeader` and `CellValue`, I've got no choice but to make a factory that injects the SQL connection.

Comment: yes, I think I would say you have a whole bunch of choices and you have perhaps selected a bad one. But without seeing the code I cant tell#

Comment: @Ewan There's really no more code to show. All that the factories will do is let us build a `Handler` without needing to specify the `SqlConnection`.

Comment: im guessing here but do you have code like `Customer.Save() //uses injected repo`?

Comment: @Ewan Yeah, so the `CustomerHandler` might take `CustomerID` and `SqlConnection` in its constructor, but we will let the factory deal with the `SqlConnection` part for us. All that `Form1` will know about is that it has a `CustomerHandlerFactory` that takes in `CustomerID` and spits out a `Customer` that knows how to talk to the server.

Comment: I would have `repo.Save(customer)` instead. Think you will find that it solves lots of your problems

Comment: @Ewan Thanks. If you can link to an example, then I will read it with great interest.

Comment: if you add an example of your code, i could flip it around for you.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/439770/c-class-creating-instances-of-other-classes-requiring-different-services/439772#439772

Comment: @Ewan Example added.

Comment: @Ewan Have a link to that "work out the type for you" thing?

Comment: https://www.infoq.com/news/2019/01/c-sharp-targeted-type-new/ i guess? must have used it all over the place in one liners but constructor chaining them was an eye opener. Think of the needless characters saved!!!!

Comment: @Ewan: AFAIK the type inference for `new` will not work here. since all constructor parameters are interfaces here, not the actual classes.

Comment: possibly, not clear from example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your doubts about the design are caused by the amount of boilerplate and repetitous looking code - so lets try to fix this. Then you can answer yourself afterwards whether the design is "good enough" in your perception.

1. First thing I would question here is if each of your factories really needs a new `SqlContext` object. Creating a new `SqlContext` once and pass it into all factories could remove some duplicate logic here and simplify the code a little bit. In case that's not possible, you may consider to avoid the repetition of the SqlConnString utilizing a `Func` like this:

   ```
   private static RootType CompRoot2(string SqlConnString)
   {
       var createSqlContext = () => new SqlContext(SqlConnString);

        new Form1(
              new FooCellsHandlerFactory(
                  new FooSqlRepository(createSqlContext())
              ),
              new TimeCellsHandlerFactory(
                  new TimeSqlRepository(createSqlContext())
              ),
              // ...
   ```

   Note `createSqlContext` is effectively a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).
2. Now let me address the large number of factories. Your form contains several different cell types which need to be handled differently.You may consider to use only *one* kind of object called `CellHandler` or `CellHandlerService`, which is passed into the form. This object can internally have different "special handlers" (`FooCellHandler`, `BarCellsHandler`, ... ) for the individual cell types (maybe using different classes, maybe not), and also the factories for those cell types. This approach is known as "introducing  a Facade Service", as [Mark Seemann called it](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/). It will not necessarily reduce the overall number of factories in your program, but reduce the number of constructor parameters of your form.

   I would also expect to have some common logic in the new service class which can be shared for all types of cells, maybe even a shared repo for all of them, or a shared SqlContext (but this is impossible to tell without actually seeing the real code). Maybe it makes it possible to have a more generic kind of factory which can produce different types of cells in a parametric fashion.  Another approach could be to make use of the [Prototype design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) inside the service, which might also reduce the number of required factories. But even if you cannot avoid the different handler types internally, or cannot simplify the logic, the responsibilities in your code will become clearer this way.
3. When your factory **classes** are effectively just a container for one function with one bound variable, consider to replace them by factory **functions** in form of closures. This isn't a change in the overall design, but reduces the amount of boilerplate code, since you do not have to write a full-blown factory class for each and every case. For example:

   ```
   private static RootType CompRoot2(string SqlConnString)
   {
       var createSqlContext = () => new SqlContext(SqlConnString);

       var fooRepo = new FooSqlRepo(createSqlContext());
       var fooCellsHandlerFactory= () => new FooCellsHander(); 

       var timeRepo = new TimeSqlRepo(createSqlContext());
       var timeCellHandlerFactory =  (CellValue, CellHeader) 
                       => new TimeCellHandler(CellValue, CellHeader, timeRepo);

        new Form1(
              fooCellsHandlerFactory,
              timeCellHandlerFactory, 
              // ...
   ```

   This example should also answer your [former question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/446007/when-refactoring-many-functions-that-share-state-in-to-a-single-class-how-can-y) how to avoid "escort classes".

Comment: This is absolutely excellent and shows many ways to simply my design. It has just one omission: Is my composition root needing many of these factories a sign of bad design?

Comment: @J.Mini: the sheer number of factories will not tell you if the design is good or bad. If you are going to write individual unit tests for which all these different factories are required, then you probably need them all. But maybe when introducing a facade service, it could turn out you will only need a single factory for that service itself, so you can mock it out with one mock factory for all your tests. This is case dependend and can only be answered sensibly by looking at the real code.

Comment: ... another approach to reduce the number of factories in this case could be to make use of the Prototype pattern, see my edit.

Comment: Coincidentally, I've just reached the part in Mark Seesman's *Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, And Patterns* that mentions Facade Services. It's quite surprising that nobody mentioned the overarching topic of that chapter, namely that "constructor over-injection" is not an anti-pattern but is a code smell.

Comment: @J.Mini: well, at least I told you to look at the idea of a facade service to reduce the number of constructor parameters of your Form1. "constructor over-injection" sounds like a good name for this phenomen, but  it is probably not so popular that it I think it is *"surprising that nobody mentioned [it]"*.

Comment: Interestingly, page 272 of that same book advises against depending on `Func`s. Either its reasoning is unconvincing or it went over my head.

Comment: @J.Mini: I don't have that book, but I guess Seemann does not write "never use Func" (as well as I did not tell you always use Func as a replacement for interfaces).

Answer (score 1):

A composition root doesn't have to stand completely alone. Sure, it gives you a lot of flexibility if it's flat and procedural but the longer that gets the more it [numbs the brain](https://github.com/yegor256/rultor/blob/1.34/src/main/java/com/rultor/agents/Agents.java). Always keep in mind what it's going to be like maintaining this code.

It is perfectly ok to break up this code and make something else deal with some of this complexity. Keep what's managed here simple and accessible. That way, looking at it, and changing it, is relaxing. Not overwhelming.

A humble example:

```
private static Form1 Form1Factory(string SqlConnString)
{
    return
        new Form1(
            new FooCellsFactoryBuilder(
                new SqlContext(SqlConnString)
            ).build(),
            new BarCellsFactoryBuilder(
                new SqlContext(SqlConnString)
            ).build(),
            new OtherCellsFactoryBuilder(
                new SqlContext(SqlConnString)
            ).build(),
            new MyColumnFactoryBuilder(
                new SqlContext(SqlConnString)
            ).build(),
            new EdgeCaseFactoryBuilder(
                new SqlContext(SqlConnString)
            ).build(),
        )
    ;
}
```

Comment: So, in summary, "there's nothing wrong with what you're doing and here is an even better way to do it"?

Comment: @J.Mini well, like anything, it can be taken to far. So here's another direction to go in. But again, like anything, it can be taken to far.

Comment: Note that, if you move "new xxxxRepository" to its respective factory, you get the same code ... literally. The "code smell" is not on the so many news in the composition root, which is expected to have several; the issue is in Form1 composition (IMO). It would have made a big deal improvement to create a syntaxis sugar FormBuilder instead..,

Comment: “Syntaxis sugar FormBuilder” can you show us an example?

Comment: Something in the lines `new FormBuilder(SqlConnString).withFooCellsFactory().withEdgeCaseFactoryBuilder().build()`. If we are going to move "new" to builders, let's move'em all to a single one

Comment: @Laiv wasn't going after the `new`'s so much as the redundancy. Your scheme works nicely when the factories are optional rather than all required. Unless you're making a full blown DSL.

Comment: Well, we don't know how many Forms has the OP. We could remove the syntaxis sugar and leave a single .build() too.

Answer (score 0):

Its really the interaction between the model and the repository which I would focus on.

In your example you have a TimeCellHandler, which has the value, cell and repository encapsulated and various Save CRUD methods.

You don't show what methods you have on the repository or Form.

Lets imagine though that we have a Root object as such:

```
Grid
{
    List<Cell> Cells
}

Cell
{
    string CellType
    string ValueAsString(){..}
    int X,
    int Y
}

Cell<T> : Cell
{
   T value 
}
```

Now I can have a repository

```
GridRepository
{
    void SaveGrid(Grid grid); //saves whole grid
    //if needed
    void SaveCell(string gridId, Cell cell);
    ...etc
}
```

And Form

```
Form
{
    Grid MyGrid
    IGridRepository repo

    void Save()
    {
         //call grid repo methods to save grid, or portions of grid as required.
    }
}
```

Instead of having the save methods on the model, they go on a repository which takes the model as a parameter. This saves you injecting the repo and related issues.

Now you might complain that You will have to cast the Cell to the correct type via reflection to get at the underlying typed value. There are some workarounds you could use to avoid this, but I would argue that its fine in what basically amounts to a serialisation layer.